Producer Consumer in Java hitting IllegalMonitorStateException and program not terminating
I have written the below producer consumer code:
package com.example.springlearn1.demo;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

class Producer implements Runnable {
    Random rand = new Random();
    ReentrantLock lk;
    Condition cp;
    Condition cc;
    LinkedList<Integer> l;
    int cap;
    public Producer(LinkedList<Integer> l, ReentrantLock lk, int cap, Condition cp, Condition cc) {
        this.l = l;
        this.lk = lk;
        this.cap = cap;
        this.cp = cp;
        this.cc = cc;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                lk.lock();
                System.out.println("In producer");
                while(l.size() == cap) {
                    cp.await();
                }
                cc.signalAll();
                if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    System.out.println("Producer Aborting now...\n");
                    break;
                }
                l.addLast(rand.nextInt(4000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    System.out.println("Producer Thread is interrupted.");
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                //throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                lk.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {
    ReentrantLock lk;
    LinkedList<Integer> l;
    Condition cp;
    Condition cc;
    int cap;
    public Consumer(LinkedList<Integer> l, ReentrantLock lk, int cap, Condition cp, Condition cc) {
        this.l = l;
        this.lk = lk;
        this.cap = cap;
        this.cp = cp;
        this.cc = cc;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                lk.lock();
                System.out.println("In consumer");
                while(l.size() == 0) {
                    cc.await();
                }
                cp.signalAll();
                if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    System.out.println("Aborting now...\n");
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("Element is "+l.removeFirst());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    System.out.println("Consumer Thread is interrupted.");
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                //throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                lk.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
public class ProducerConsumer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        LinkedList<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        Condition cp = lock.newCondition();
        Condition cc = lock.newCondition();
        int capacity = 10;

        Thread producerThread = new Thread(new Producer(queue, lock, capacity, cp,cc));
        Thread consumerThread = new Thread(new Consumer(queue, lock, capacity,cp,cc));

        consumerThread.start();
        producerThread.start();
        System.out.println("Started both threads");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60000); // Run for 1 minute
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Threads interrupted, exiting.");
        }

        producerThread.interrupt();
        consumerThread.interrupt();
        producerThread.join();
        consumerThread.join();
    }
}

The code starts running, prints traces from producer and consumer and also random numbers, but eventually, it errors out as below and the code does not even terminate
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:175)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1007)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock(ReentrantLock.java:494)
    at com.example.springlearn1.demo.Consumer.run(ProducerConsumer.java:89)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
In producer

Line 89 in my ide is
lk.unlock in the Consumer.
I am not able to understand why this state occurs after a while. The is supposed to run for 1 minute and then terminate.

I can't reproduce it. Are you sure you posted your exact code?

java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException occurs when calling unlock to release an unheld lock. In your code, this exception could be because the thread was interrupted during Thread.sleep, causing the lock to not be held when entering the finally block. To solve this problem, you need to make sure to check whether the lock is held before unlocking it.
            finally {
                if (lk.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
                    lk.unlock();
                }
            }


java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException typically occurs when an attempt is made to release an unheld lock. In your code, this exception could be because the thread was interrupted after the await call, causing the lock to not be held when the unlock call was made. To solve this problem, you need to make sure to check whether the lock is held before unlocking it.

I added your comment to your answer. Since it is a relevant part of the answer it shouldn't be a comment.

A couple of things:
you 'll have to remove/mute/comment the join()s. Reason-

joining a thread means waiting for it to terminate

read more here.
But, you are only 'interrupting' later, and in fact, run your code in the debugger and put a 'breakpoint' on line for producerThread.interrupt(), and you'll never get there, because no where in the threads is any implicit interrupt happening!
thus, do:
        consumerThread.start();
        producerThread.start();
        System.out.println("Started both threads");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60000); // Run for 1 minute
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Threads interrupted, exiting.");
        }
//        producerThread.join();
//        consumerThread.join();
        producerThread.interrupt();
        consumerThread.interrupt();

Secondly, in the overriden run() of both the threads,
You are explictly 'catching' the InterruptedException.
This happens when your code hits producerThread.interrupt() and consumerThread.interrupt() after completing 60secs.
However, since you 'explicitly' caught the exception, your code shall never enter the block:
if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) { ...

What you can ideally, simply do, is either:

throw a RuntimeException. it explicitly interrupts the thread! (recommended)
Don't catch any exception, at all! i.e all the run() implementation is a single block, and no try/catch.
never simply interrupt()a thread- because it will come out of sleep, but still not stop working (forbidden)

check the image below, for case#3

Also, read more on the above 3 cases/points, here.
Lastly, the right way, to "unlock" a reentrant lock, shall be to first check if the current thread is actually holding your lock-
By introducing a breakpoint on lk.unlock() statements in both the "finally" blocks, I found that the state of the Reentrant lock 'lk' was 0 = 'unacquired'. see this.
Thus, the correct way here is:
...
            } finally {
                if (lk.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
                    lk.unlock();
                }
            }
...

Let me know if you need the final working code. After making above changes, my application gracefully stops after 60secs(set Thread.sleep time). It throws thread sleep interrupted exception.
To further handle gracefully, wrap the .interrupt() calls in try/catch blocks and print statements like "producerThread interrupted", "consumerThread Interrupted", respectively!

The problem lies in your usage of try/catch/finally. You're using these blocks to protect the lock and make sure it gets acquired and released properly. That is good, the bad is you're including another error in the blocks that can subvert your attempts.
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    lk.lock();
    ...

In this snippet, your sleep call could get interrupted and you'll never acquire the lock. The other two solutions have proposed checking if the lock is held before releasing it. An alternative way is to remove the Thread.sleep from the lock's try/catch/finally.
try{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch(InterruptedException e){
     throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
try{
    lk.lock();
    ...

The reason I would suggest this way, is because it's separating the protections you end up just guarding the lock with your second try/catch/finally.

More than one other answer suggests that you call lk.isHeldByCurrentThread(). But, there's another way. Move the lock call out of the try block:
try {
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    ...
    return;
}

lk.lock();   // Cannot ever fail. Will not throw an exception.
try {
    ...
}
finally {
    lk.unlock();
}

Which way you choose pretty much is just a matter of style. Either way will fix your problem.
